# print file pdf from viewer bird report on firefox and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, pdf, birt

I use eclipse + richfaces + birt report create j2ee web application.
When i export one report to pdf file it can be viewed on firefox and chrome (base viewer of birt report). Then, i print that report from firefox and chrome, i see 2 papers do not match.
But i download to 2 pdf file (firefox and chrome) and print them, they are the same.
I don't know why they are not the same if direct print from 2 browsers (or other browsers).
I think viewer of birt report maybe display diffent on different browsers.
Addtion : i use foxit reader to read pdf file. I test print the same file from foxit and adobe acrobat, they are not match. You can view here :
[demo.crmviet.vn](http://demo.crmviet.vn)
, **user** : demo
, **pass** : 123456
, *view pdf : (menu) Quản lý chung -> Quản lý báo giá -> In phiếu (on the left) -> (open a popup) -> Xuất pdf.*
How can i print pdf file from firefox and chrome do match ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your own question: The PDF renderers used in your 2 browsers are not the same. One point which is often overlooked is the "adapt page size" option in the print dialog (please note that I do not know how this is called exactly in an English Adobe Reader):
By default, many renderers will shrink the page while printing (to avoid cropping content at the printer's hardware margin).
To compare the output, you should always set the option to "print at original size".

Apart from that, Adobe Reader is the de-facto reference implementation.

Most output differences between Adobe Reader and other renderers are caused by PDFs not complying to the PDF specification - this should not be the case for PDFs generated by BIRT, however. Adobe Reader is very forgiving and "does the right thing", while other renderers just fail when they're stumbling across incorrect PDFs or produce crippled output.